# Comparing two date values coming from nested for loops in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I am comparing two date values in XSLT. Value A is coming from the outermost loop and Value B is coming from a for loop which is inside. But doing a comparison of these values inside the inner loop always gives me false as result although when printing these values, I can see these are same.

Source XML:

```
  <root>
  <fs:Fruits xmlns:fs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/fs">
        <fs:Action>CHANGE</fs:Operation>
        <fs:Fruit_Available_Start_Date>20140607</fs:Fruit_Available_Start_Date>
        <fs:Fruit_Available_End_Date>20150201</Fruit_Available_End_Date>
  </fs:Fruits>
    <fs:Fruits>
        <fs:Action>NEW</fs:Operation>
        <fs:Fruit_Available_Start_Date>20150502</fs:Fruit_Available_Start_Date>
  </fs:Fruits>
    <fs:Fruits>
        <fs:Action>NEW</fs:Operation>
        <fs:Fruit_Available_Start_Date>20150202</fs:Fruit_Available_Start_Date>
  </fs:Fruits>
    <fs:Fruits>
        <fs:Action>CHANGE</fs:Operation>
        <fs:Fruit_Available_Start_Date>20150402</fs:Fruit_Available_Start_Date>
        <fs:Fruit_Available_End_Date>20150201</Fruit_Available_End_Date>
  </fs:Fruits>
  </root>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/fs"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="//fs:Fruits[fs:Action = 'CHANGE']">
            <xsl:sort select="fs:Fruit_Available_End_Date" order="descending"></xsl:sort>
            <xsl:variable name="FruitAvailableEndDatePluseOneDay" select="xs:date(concat(substring(fs:Fruit_Available_End_Date,1,4),'-',substring(fs:Fruit_Available_End_Date,5,2),'-',substring(fs:Fruit_Available_End_Date,7,2))) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"></xsl:variable>            
            <xsl:for-each select="//fs:Fruits[fs:Action = 'NEW']">
                <xsl:variable name="Fruit_Available_Start_Date" select="xs:date(concat(substring(fs:Fruit_Available_Start_Date,1,4),'-',substring(fs:Fruit_Available_Start_Date,5,2),'-',substring(fs:Fruit_Available_Start_Date,7,2)))"></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:if test="$Fruit_Available_Start_Date = $FruitAvailableEndDatePluseOneDay">
                    <xsl:value-of select="hello"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is currently blank

Comment: Please show us the relevant code snippets of XML input, XSLT, result you get and the one you want.

Comment: Instead of describing loops, show a minimal example of the code that exhibits this behaviour. Together with sample XML input and output documents. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: We need to see the sample input data as well.

Comment: ... we need to see sample output as well, and a _complete_ XSLT stylesheet. Please really do read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Thanks.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - Updated the XML and XSL

Comment: `<fs:Action>CHANGE</fs:Operation>` is not well-formed XML.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="hello"></xsl:value-of>
```

which refers to a non-existing element named `hello`, try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="'hello'"/>
```

or - preferably:

```
<xsl:text>hello</xsl:text>
```